# Read APK permission by shell command

Tags: permissions, apk, shell, command-line, android-sdk

I want to read the requested permissions of an .apk file on the computer (android sdk is installed) via command line.

I.E.:

```
$ android read-permissions /path/to/someapp.apk
```

I know this is possible, I just cant find the proper command.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If I'm interpreting "on the computer" correctly to mean "I want to use the command line on my computer to read an .apk file's permissions" then you can do that with `aapt` on a local file like so:

```
C:\>aapt d permissions "MyApp.apk"
package: com.app.myapp
uses-permission: android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE
uses-permission: android.permission.INTERNET
```

If you mean that the .apk is on the device, then I'm not aware of a way to do this aside from pulling it and running `aapt` as above. `pm` has a `list permissions` command but it just lists all available permissions on the device and does not accept a package as a parameter (as far as I know, anyway).

Comment: If you are on Mac, you will have to get the path to your `aapt`, based on the `build-tools` for Android, something like this, just change the placeholders for your username (of the Mac), build-tools version and path to the APK you want to test:

`sudo /Users/YOUR_USER_NAME/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/BUILD_TOOLS_SDK_VERSION/aapt d permissions 'path_to_the_apk_file'`

Answer (score 1):

On the device it will probably be easier to look for the relevant section in

/data/system/packages.xml

(which *can* be read, even though its directory cannot be browsed or listed) as this is a text file, while the AndroidManifest.xml in an apk is in a compressed format.

There is code around on the net for interpreting the compressed manifests on the device, but that's a bit more complicated.