# Package installer: show all permissions

Tags: applications, installation, permissions

In older versions of Android, the package installer used to show *all* permissions an app requested – and so did "Android Market" and later also "Google Play Store". A few years ago, the latter started to only show *selected* permissions, or rather permission groups ("uses one of those permissions" – without saying which). Now it seems with Marshmallow the package installer followed on that insane road, only showing permission groups.

I don't want a "guess", I want facts. When I install an app, I want to see what permissions it requests – *exactly.* Especially when I apply an update, I not only want to be informed about additional *groups* requested from, but exactly what permissions have been added – even if some other permission of the same group has already been granted before.

---

**TL;DR:** How to make the package installer show *all* permissions an app-to-be-installed requests?

---

Rooted approaches acceptable, also if requiring Magisk or Xposed. If doable without any of those, all the better.

Comment: PlaypermissionsExposed xposed module may partly meet your needs. It claims to prevent update of new permissions added and shows all permissions on Play Store. Haven't used it in a while though

Comment: @beeshyams thanks, but I'm not asking for the playstore app (which is not even present on the Google-free device) but about the AOSP package installer. I know about PlaypermissionsExposed and have used it in the past. But even that hasn't been updated for a while and AFAIR doesn't work on recent Playstore versions (for about a year or so).

Comment: Does this need a higher doted bounty – or is there really no solution to it?

Comment: LineageOS displays permissions, but I'll need to check when I get home if it as detailed as you want and what version that was exactly.  It may have been removed in Oreo but I'm not sure.  How detailed are you looking for?  Surely you don't mean the actually Android permission name.  Even if LO has this that doesn't exactly solve this questions issue.

Comment: @William My device runs on Lineage (MM), and the permissions shown have been reduced to what that Playstore App had reduced it before. So if the package installer on LOS still had it, my question were obsolete for me (though possibly useful to others) …

Comment: I would add a picture of what you want or some examples.

Comment: @William what I want should be quite obvious: ALL permissions an app requests should be shown – and not some hidden (as e.g. "Internet" because it's considered "not dangerous", or some other permission because one of the same group has already been granted before a specific update).

Comment: So an app that extracts android permissions like this command is an acceptable format https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/9775  having done some android development makes the most sense to me.

Comment: Not at all. I want those permissions shown at install time – not after an app has been installed. Please read the question again, @William – it says "How to make the **package installer** show all permissions", not "(some)how to show all permissions an app has". There are plenty of apps for the latter.